# Haskell how can I compare the occurrence between two strings based on the first and second character?

Tags: list, haskell

Sorry for asking a trivial question, I am new for Haskell programming,
I qm struggling with comparison between two strings

the two lists are

```
a :: [String]
a = ["A2","B3","A1"]

b::[String]
b= ["C1","A3,"A6"]
```

and I want to compare the same part based on the first character and second character and return two Int, that is (2,2)
because there are 2 strings the first character are the same, based on list b,that is 2 As both exist in two lists,based on the comparison,

```
list a ["A2","A1"]
```

and

```
list b["A3","A6"]
```

base on list b, there are 2 As, each occurred in list a once, so the first Int would return 2

and second Int comes from the comparison between the second character  based on list b, the concept is basically the same as the first Int,

> by comparing list a and list b, elements in a ["B3","A1"], and elements in b ["C1","A3"] ,1 occurred once in list a, increment 1 and ignored, 3 is occurred in list a, increment, and the return would be 2

and final return would be (2,2)
and my achieve is :
I was trying to return two Int using two functions my first one is this:
it return the first Int

```
byCompare ::[String]->[String] -> (Int,[String])  
byCompare [] x = (0, x)
byCompare x [] = (0, [])    
byCompare (x:xs)(y:ys)
  | comparehead x y == True =  increment (byCompare xs ys)
  | otherwise = append y (byCompare [x] ys) 
  where 
    increment (count, results) = (count + 1,results)
    append y (count, results) = (count, y:results)
    comparehead a b 
      | head a == head b = True
      | otherwise = False
```

The return String is what I want to figure out what is going on with my code, and It returns me a wrong answer (1,["C1","A6"]) the desired Int return should be 2 ,and String return should be ["C1","A3,"A6"], probably,and I want to use those result to my calculation of second Int, 
but I have no idea about how to fix this code to yield the right answer,

Can I combine the two codes together like

```
bigCombine ::[String] ->[String] ->(Int,Int)?
```

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: What is the purpose of `byCompare` returning a `(Int, [String])` instead of just `Int`? A general strategy to approach this: represent your data as `[(Char, Int)]` instead of `[String]` to reflect the intended contents of the data; use `unzip :: [(a,b)] -> ([a], [b])` to get the two lists separately; write a function `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which returns a list with those elements occurring in both input lists; compose this with `length`; and finally call this function on both components of the pair produced by `unzip`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in your question. The first part seems easy: you've got a list of Strings of two chars and you want to do some comparison on the first char and then some comparison on the second char.

You just have to isolate the first char and the second char:

```
Prelude> a = ["A2","B3","A1"]
Prelude> head<$>a
"ABA"
Prelude> last<$>a
"231"
```

`<$>` is the `fmap` operator : the function (`head` or `last`) is applied to every element of the list `a`.

Now you've got two separated lists. How to "compare" the chars from the two lists? This part seems more complex because what you are trying to achieve is not clear to me.

Here's a proposal: 1. count the number of each char in the two lists, 2. for every char present in the two lists, keep the number of times that char is present in both lists, that is the minimum of the count of that char in both  list. An example will be more easy to undestand: if you have three `A`s in the first list and two in the second, you keep two as value for `A`.

To get a count of every character, you can use an associative array (or "hash map"):

```
Prelude> import Data.Map
Prelude Data.Map> f l = fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <-head<$>l]
Prelude Data.Map> f a
fromList [('A',2),('B',1)]
```

You recognize `head<$>a`: it is simply the list of the first chars in `a`, that is `"ABA"` (=`['A', 'B', 'A']`). Now you build an associative array with the elements of the array as keys. The values are computed as the the number of times each key is present. (`1` if the key appear once, `1 + 1` if it appears twice, and so on): that's the `With (+)` part that applies to the `1`s of the pairs.

For the list `b`, you have:

```
Prelude Data.Map> b = ["C1","A3","A6"]
Prelude Data.Map> f b
fromList [('A',2),('C',1)]
```

It's time to compare the two associative arrays.

```
Prelude Data.Map> g l1 l2 = intersectionWithKey(\c n1 n2->min n1 n2)(f l1)(f l2)
Prelude Data.Map> g a b
fromList [('A',2)]
```

`intersectionWithKey` keeps only the keys that exists in both lists. The lambda function takes the minimum of counts and assigns it as value for that key.

Finally, you just have to compute the sum of the values of the resulting map:

```
Prelude Data.Map> Data.Map.foldl(+)0(g a b)
2
```

`foldl` makes the sum of the values.

You just have to repeat the process for the numbers (use `last`).